# How to implement a secondary custom method for object slicing, other than __getitem__ in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to implement a custom method in my class which helps users slice based on index. The primary slicing will be based on dictionary key. I want to implement it similar to how Pandas does it, using `df.iloc[n]`

here's my code:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, map_object: dict):
        self.dictionary = map_object
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        data = self.dictionary[key]
        return data

    def iloc(self, n):
        key = list(self.dictionary)[n]
        return self.dictionary[key]
```

However, if then write `object.iloc[3]` after creating the object, I get an error saying `'method' object is not subscriptable`. So how can I implement this?

Comment: iloc isn't a method - you need to expose a plain attribute or a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` `]` syntax requires a proper object with a `__getitem__` method. In order to have a "slice method", use a `property` that returns a helper which supports slicing.

The helper simply holds a reference to the actual `parent` object, and defines a `__getitem__` with the desired behaviour:

```py
class VectorIloc:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    # custom logic for desired "iloc" behaviour
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        key = list(self.parent.dictionary)[item]
        return self.parent[key]
```

On the actual class, merely define the desired "method" as a `property` that returns the helper or as an attribute:

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, map_object: dict):
        self.dictionary = map_object
        # if .iloc is used often
        # self.iloc = VectorIloc(self)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dictionary[key]

    # if .iloc is used rarely
    @property
    def iloc(self):
        return VectorIloc(self)
```

Whether to use a `property` or an attribute is an optimisation that trades memory for performance: an attribute constructs and stores the helper always, while a `property` constructs it only on-demand but on each access. A [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) can be used as a middle-ground, creating the attribute on first access.
The `property` is advantageous when the helper is used rarely per object, and especially if it often is not used at all.

---

Now, when calling `vector.iloc[3]`, the `vector.iloc` part provides the helper and the `[3]` part invoces the helper's `__getitem__`.

```py
>>> vector = Vector({0:0, 1: 1, 2: 2, "three": 3})
>>> vector.iloc[3]
3
```

Comment: Thanks. While I had already figured out the answer, something interesting I notice in yours is the differentiation based on how often they are used. Could you please explain this to me. I thought methods with `@property` decorator behaved the same way as attributes

Comment: @gouravkr An attribute and ``property`` "look" the same to code accessing either. However, an attribute constantly lives on the object – so the cost of creating the helper is always paid and it takes up memory – while a ``property`` is executable code – so the cost of creating the helper is paid again and again on each access. The usability is the same in this case, but you are effectively trading memory (for storing the attribute) versus performance (for accessing the property).

Comment: @gouravkr By the way, this is a really nice self-answered question! I couldn't tell that you already knew the answer just by looking at the question.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to post it in case someone looks for it in future. And there's always something new to learn, like the difference between attribute and property :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this implementation which I'm pretty used to in Pandas. However, after searching a lot, I could not find any suitable answer. So I went looking through the Pandas source code and found that the primary requirement for implementing this are as follows:

1. Create the method with `@property` decorator, so that it accepts the slice object without throwing the above error
2. Create a second class to slice based on the index, pass self to this class, and return this class from the method

My final code ended up looking something like this:

```
class TimeSeries:
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.data = data
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        data = self.data[key]
        return data
    
    @property
    def iloc(self):
        return Slicer(self)

class Slicer:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.time_series = obj
        
    def __getitem__(self, n):
        key = list(self.time_series.data)[n]
        return self.time_series[key]
```

With the classes defined this way, I could write the following code:

```
>>> ts = TimeSeries({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
>>> print("value of a:", ts['a'])
value of a: 1

>>> print("value at position 0:", ts.iloc[0])
value at position 0: 1
```